# Script won't run properly in crontab, no path or permission problems

Tags: bash, cron, geany

I use the geany text editor, which has a command line option to list all open documents. The following command works fine when run from the command line:

```
/usr/bin/geany --list-documents > /home/myname/geanylist.txt
```

I want to run this regularly in cron, but it does not work. I have tried:

- putting the above command directly into my crontab
- wrapping the above command in a bash script, and calling that in my crontab
- defining all normal path and other environment variables in the script
- copying the entire contents of my .bashrc into the script
- redirecting stderr and stdout to a log file (no help)

No matter what I do, when the crontab runs, ~/geanylist.txt will not contain the output from `geany --list-documents`, though it will contain any other output generated by the script. I am at a loss. How can I make this work? Is there another system utility besides cron I can use that will let me do this?

The best solution I can think of is to create a script with a loop that runs the command and then sleeps for 24 hours - surely there is a better way?

edit:

- The result of `/usr/bin/geany --list-documents`, when run from the CL, is a list of full paths to (usually ascii txt) files, one per line, on stdout.
- When adding the command or script to my crontab, I use `crontab -e`, with `$EDITOR` set to `nano`. This is the same way I have added many other commands to my crontab, all of which work properly (none of these other commands attempt to run `geany` in any way).

Comment: What is the output of `/usr/bin/geany --list-documents` and how you add the task to the crontab? `crontab -e`, `sudo crontab -e`?

Comment: @Braiam: see edit at bottom of main post.

Answer (score 2):

A wild guess: geany running from cron does not have access to your DISPLAY; try adding `DISPLAY=:0`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't help.

Comment: You were right about this, but for reasons I don't understand, the solution is to pass the display as an option to geany, rather than to define the environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

Solution found here: https://sourceforge.net/p/geany/bugs/999/

`* * * * * /usr/bin/geany --display=:0.0 --list-documents > /home/myname/geany_files.txt`